# Multithread webservice?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, web-services

I need to write a program that is calculation intensive. So I need to load data from database into memory before I do the calculation (to save time for fetching data from database each time.

I want the program to be a webservice, and want many clients to be able to run multiple calcuations at the same time.

Since the load data takes quite some memory, I want all calculations to be sharing the same data(global data).

However, if two users call for loading the same data at the same time, would there be a synchronization issue, when one is already loading the data, and the 2nd begin to load the same data again.

Do I need to do some thread lock especially for this? Does webservice mean multi-thread programming? I plan to use WWS(windows web service), since I am a C++ programmer, but only handled pure algorithms before, so this is new to me.

Sorry if I confuse you.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to distinguish each client reliably, you can create a context for each one, and that context may expire if the client disconnects or remains idle for a specified amount of time.

Additionally, if you want to allow each client to do multiple "calculation requests" simultaneously, you need a unique way to identify each of these requests, and keep track of them in the client context. For example, if a user has 1 processing task, and 2 queued tasks, then his context is tracking 3 tasks simultaneously, and each of them has its own state (queued, running, and completed).

To identify when a "calculation request" is done processing, the client could stay *polling* your service, informing the unique identifier for the "calculation request" it's interested in.

Whether locking is required or not, depends on the architecture you adopt to solve the problem. Is your "global data" read-only? If yes, then you don't need a lock to access it. Otherwise, you most likely do (still depends on how this data is stored). I would suggest using an HTTP web service, and rely on sessions (cookies) to track each user. But since I don't know your requirements, that is a shot in the dark. If you follow the design I suggest here, and are going to use a thread-per-connection, then you'll need at least one lock per context (given an user may send multiple requests simultaneously) and one lock to guard the access to the context list.

Comment: My architecture is Database layer: Oracle(Database, plus Oracle OCCI)+ Logical layer:C++, plus windows web service(WWS) + Presentation layer: WCF client, either web or winform.              The program is to do monte carlo simulation 5000 times each for 20000 financial instruments per day. The database query is bottleneck, so I want to buffer the data into memory for users to quickly access. But the dataloader should know if some data needs to be loaded and load them on demand, thus the request for lock.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your data loading problem, look to use the singleton pattern where the singleton would have a load method that would check to see if the data is loaded.  If not loaded a mutex/monitor/etc would be acquired, check again if the data is loaded, if not load the data and set the data loaded flag, release the mutex/monitor/etc.

No web server do not have to be multithreaded. Depending on what middleware manages client interactions it should be possible to specify that all service requests be processed sequentially. Keep in mind that if you are running on a multiprocessor system you will only be able to use a fraction of the processing ability.

If your server does not modify any shared data it is possible it would need little or no synchronization to have correct/proper multithreaded behavior. The complexity of the locking code will be proportional to the amount of shared data that is modified and the level of contention to the modified data there is.